# Spring MVC Bean Validation with Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm using Java configuration for Spring MVC.  I can't get Bean Validation to work.  I have a domain class that I've annotated and I want to use `@Valid` in my Controller.  I know that with XML configuration, I would set the validator this way `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>`

How can I do this with Java configuration.  I'm not getting any errors, the validation just doesn't work.  Thanks in advance!

Here is my set up:

Domain class with the annotations:

```
public class Product {

    @Pattern(regexp="P[1-9]+", message="{Pattern.Product.productId.validation}")
    @ProductId 
    private String productId;

    @Size(min=4, max=50, message="{Size.Product.name.validation}")
    private String name;

    @Min(value=0, message="Min.Product.unitPrice.validation}")
    @Digits(integer=8, fraction=2, message="{Digits.Product.unitPrice.validation}")
    @NotNull(message= "{NotNull.Product.unitPrice.validation}")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;
    private String description;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String category;
    private long unitsInStock;
```

Here is my Controller using @Valid:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

..... (shortened)

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAddNewProductForm(@ModelAttribute("newProduct") Product newProduct) {
       return "addProduct";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processAddNewProductForm(@ModelAttribute("newProduct") @Valid Product productToBeAdded, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "addProduct";
        }

        String[] suppressedFields = result.getSuppressedFields();

        if (suppressedFields.length > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to bind disallowed fields: " + StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(suppressedFields));
        }

        MultipartFile productImage = productToBeAdded.getProductImage();
        String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

            if (productImage!=null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
               try {
                productImage.transferTo(new File(rootDirectory+"resources\\images\\"+productToBeAdded.getProductId() + ".png"));
               } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Product Image saving failed", e);
           }
           }


        productService.addProduct(productToBeAdded);
        return "redirect:/products";
    }
```

Here is my Config class with @EnableWebMVC: (*****Updated to get validator*****)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.nam.webstore"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

..... (shortened)

    @Bean(name = "validator")
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean lvfb = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();

        lvfb.setValidationMessageSource(resourceBundleMessageSource());

        return lvfb;
    }

    (***** Updated *****)
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return localValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Here is the jsp with the error tags:

```
..... (shortened)

<section class="container">
    <form:form  modelAttribute="newProduct" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add new product</legend>

            <form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert alert-danger" element="div"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-lg-2" for="productId"><spring:message code="addProduct.form.productId.label"/></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <form:input id="productId" path="productId" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                    <form:errors path="productId" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="name"><spring:message code="addProduct.form.name.label"/></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <form:input id="name" path="name" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                    <form:errors path="name" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="unitPrice"><spring:message code="addProduct.form.unitPrice.label"/></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="form:input-prepend">
                        <form:input id="unitPrice" path="unitPrice" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                        <form:errors path="unitPrice" cssClass="text-danger"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="description"><spring:message code="addProduct.form.description.label"/></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <form:textarea id="description" path="description" rows = "2"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Updated 
After setting the Logger to DEBUG, this is what I'm seeing in the console.  I can see that it's firing off the validation, but I don't know why it's saying I'm returning null to the DispatcherServlet?  I'm returning the view name.

> Field error in object 'newProduct' on field 'unitPrice': rejected
>   value [null]; codes
>   [NotNull.newProduct.unitPrice,NotNull.unitPrice,NotNull.java.math.BigDecimal,NotNull];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.unitPrice,unitPrice]; arguments []; default message
>   [unitPrice]]; default message [Unit price is Invalid. It cannot be
>   empty.] Field error in object 'newProduct' on field 'productId':
>   rejected value []; codes
>   [Pattern.newProduct.productId,Pattern.productId,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.productId,productId]; arguments []; default message
>   [productId],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@3641ef8a,P[1-9]+];
>   default message [Invalid product ID. It should start with character P
>   followed by number.] Field error in object 'newProduct' on field
>   'name': rejected value []; codes
>   [Size.newProduct.name,Size.name,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.name,name]; arguments []; default message
>   [name],50,4]; default message [Invalid product name. It should be
>   minimum 4 characters to maximum 50 characters long.] 2014-07-25
>   15:03:36 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving
>   exception from handler [public java.lang.String
>   com.nam.webstore.controller.ProductController.processAddNewProductForm(com.nam.webstore.domain.Product,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]:
>   org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
>   Field error in object 'newProduct' on field 'unitPrice': rejected
>   value [null]; codes
>   [NotNull.newProduct.unitPrice,NotNull.unitPrice,NotNull.java.math.BigDecimal,NotNull];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.unitPrice,unitPrice]; arguments []; default message
>   [unitPrice]]; default message [Unit price is Invalid. It cannot be
>   empty.] Field error in object 'newProduct' on field 'productId':
>   rejected value []; codes
>   [Pattern.newProduct.productId,Pattern.productId,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.productId,productId]; arguments []; default message
>   [productId],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@3641ef8a,P[1-9]+];
>   default message [Invalid product ID. It should start with character P
>   followed by number.] Field error in object 'newProduct' on field
>   'name': rejected value []; codes
>   [Size.newProduct.name,Size.name,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.name,name]; arguments []; default message
>   [name],50,4]; default message [Invalid product name. It should be
>   minimum 4 characters to maximum 50 characters long.] 2014-07-25
>   15:03:36 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving
>   exception from handler [public java.lang.String
>   com.nam.webstore.controller.ProductController.processAddNewProductForm(com.nam.webstore.domain.Product,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]:
>   org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
>   Field error in object 'newProduct' on field 'unitPrice': rejected
>   value [null]; codes
>   [NotNull.newProduct.unitPrice,NotNull.unitPrice,NotNull.java.math.BigDecimal,NotNull];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.unitPrice,unitPrice]; arguments []; default message
>   [unitPrice]]; default message [Unit price is Invalid. It cannot be
>   empty.] Field error in object 'newProduct' on field 'productId':
>   rejected value []; codes
>   [Pattern.newProduct.productId,Pattern.productId,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.productId,productId]; arguments []; default message
>   [productId],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@3641ef8a,P[1-9]+];
>   default message [Invalid product ID. It should start with character P
>   followed by number.] Field error in object 'newProduct' on field
>   'name': rejected value []; codes
>   [Size.newProduct.name,Size.name,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [newProduct.name,name]; arguments []; default message
>   [name],50,4]; default message [Invalid product name. It should be
>   minimum 4 characters to maximum 50 characters long.] 2014-07-25
>   15:03:36 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1012 - Null ModelAndView returned to
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet': assuming
>   HandlerAdapter completed request handling 2014-07-25 15:03:36 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:991 - Successfully completed request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` you can override the `getValidator()` method to have it return your custom `Validator`.

With `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, you can either call `afterPropertiesSet()` and `getObject()` to get the real `Validator`.

Comment: Sotirios, I've updated the code as you've suggested.  Now, I'm getting a 400 status.  If I remove the Valid annotation, I can submit, but the validation still doesn't work.  I've also tried using Valid annotation as the first param.

Comment: @NuAlphaMan Turn your logger level to debug. Spring will report why it returned a 400.

Comment: I've changed it to debug, and it's says I'm returning null which I don't get.  In the controller, I'm returning the view name.

Comment: Ok, I've solved the problem!  Thanks @Sotirios for your suggestions!  I will give you a check for that.  To fix BindException, I found the answer here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/78238-bindexception-thrown-on-bind-errors-instead-of-returning-errors-to-controller-method.  The BindingResult should follow the object your binding it to.

Answer (score 1):

Old subject but I had the same problem so I will paste this bean

```
@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validator;
}
```